# tabbed canvas not displayed when i click on item on content canvas

Tags: oracleforms

I'm using oracle forms 6i, I have both content canvas and tabbed canvas shown, but when I click on the input field on content canvas, the tabbed canvas disappears. How to keep it on the content form even if i click outside the tabbed canvas?

Thankyou.

Comment: Also, when i execute a query the details are not populated until i click on the tabbed canvas. I want the details to be displayed on the tabbed canvas as soon as i execute the query and not after clicking on the canvas.     Please help regarding this also...........     Thankyou...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In when-new-form-instance trigger write:

show_view('tabcanvasname');

or

In when-new-form-instance trigger write:
go_item('anytabcanvasitem'); -- change with your block.item name
go_item('anycontentcanvasitem');

Comment: thankyou for your reply..... show_view is written. and thus the tabbed canvas is displayed on startup. but after i execute any query in the content canvas and populate details of that query in the tabbed canvas and then click on the previously queried item from the content canvas, the tabbed canvas dissapears. This is the problem i am facing...

Comment: Sir, I tried what you suggested.But when i use the go_item in new_form_instance  the control is directly forwarded to the tab page. And while the control is on the tab page, if i click on the content canvas item, the tab page dissapears. My main motto over here is to keep the tab canvas displayed irrespective of wherever i click and wherever the control is present...

Answer (score 0):

You have one/more item/items under the tab canvas. when you click on out side of canvas the cursor moved to item under tab canvas. Remove the item/s under the tab canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there still is someone out using Oracle Forms Developer 6i, but in case there is, I solved the above problem by setting the "Raise on entry" property of the console canvas to "No".

On Form Module property is have set the Console Window set to the main window, and the First Navigation Block also to the main block.
Also, the main window (witch is content type) appears as first in the Windows list.
It's associated with the main canvas, with also appears as first in the Canvas list.
The main canvas has its "Raise on entry" property set to "No".

Any other combination, result as the stacked canvas appear when the focus is placed over a field showed in the stacked canvas, then as soon as the focus moves to a fied out of the stacked canvas and to the content canvas, the stacked canvas dissapear.

Hope it helps avoid hours of trail and error!